# Bourbon errors when compiled

Tags: sass, bourbon

I've installed bourbon into an empty style sheet and compiled it and I'm getting errors in Bourbon.

Bourbon 5.0.0.alpha.0

Sass 3.4.18

Cutting out these parts of Bourbon and it'll work.

```
// Bourbon 5.0.0.alpha.0
// http://bourbon.io
// Copyright 2011-2015 thoughtbot, inc.
// MIT License

@import "bourbon/settings/asset-pipeline";
@import "bourbon/settings/global-font-file-formats";
@import "bourbon/settings/scales";
@import "bourbon/settings/modular-scale";

@import "bourbon/functions/assign-inputs";
@import "bourbon/functions/contains";
@import "bourbon/functions/contains-falsy";
@import "bourbon/functions/is-length";
@import "bourbon/functions/is-light";
@import "bourbon/functions/is-number";
@import "bourbon/functions/is-size";
@import "bourbon/functions/shade";
@import "bourbon/functions/strip-unit";
@import "bourbon/functions/tint";
@import "bourbon/functions/unpack";
@import "bourbon/functions/modular-scale";

@import "bourbon/helpers/directional-values";
// @import "bourbon/helpers/font-source-declaration";

@import "bourbon/css3/font-face";

@import "bourbon/addons/border-color";
@import "bourbon/addons/border-radius";
@import "bourbon/addons/border-style";
@import "bourbon/addons/border-width";
//@import "bourbon/addons/buttons";
@import "bourbon/addons/clearfix";
@import "bourbon/addons/contrast-switch";
@import "bourbon/addons/ellipsis";
@import "bourbon/addons/font-stacks";
@import "bourbon/addons/hide-text";
@import "bourbon/addons/margin";
@import "bourbon/addons/padding";
//@import "bourbon/addons/position";
@import "bourbon/addons/prefixer";
@import "bourbon/addons/size";
//@import "bourbon/addons/text-inputs";
@import "bourbon/addons/timing-functions";
@import "bourbon/addons/word-wrap";

@import "bourbon/bourbon-deprecated";
```

The error when include all of the stylesheets above:

```
error style.scss (Line 22 of _font-source-declaration.scss: Invalid CSS after " eot": expected ")", was ": "#{$file-pa...")
```

Comment: Paste the errors and other stuff directly here.

Comment: @HappyCoder I'm not able to put images in here. I don't have enough Stack Overflow points :(

Here are the images linked again.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/cGEYf.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Azgh8.png

Comment: @HappyCoder code is included now.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was from compiling my sass with the Scout app. Apparently Scout is no longer maintained and uses an old version of sass. I've since changed to use Koala and my issues are resolved.